# Flutter android emulator System UI isn't responding

Tags: flutter

So i build an app with a lot of data and images and i use for all the images cached network image to improve the building/preview time.
After some time my app is on the fly, the emulator start to crush.
I noticed that in android virtual device manager the size on the disk is small,
like 500 mega bytes.
After some time it is growing to 12gb, i guess it's happen because i use cached network image, than every couple of seconds the UI crash.
Am i right or it can be an other problem.
How can i fix that?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using **CachedNetworkImage** is not supposed to cause the problem you described. From my experiences I have found the emulator on Android Studio to be sluggish and occasionally freezing on machines with lower RAM.
If your app doesn't have dependency on **Google Play Services**, you may try the desktop version of [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/).
**Genymotion** is smoother than the default emulator on Android Studio and also free for personal use.